# python3 keras import error with both tensorflow and theano

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, theano

With python3 (version 3.6.8) and keras
the simple script:

```
import keras
```

gives an error:

> Using TensorFlow backend.
>
> Ungültiger Maschinenbefehl (Speicherabzug geschrieben)

(in english it would be something like: "invalid machine command (memory image written)")

So I tried to use theano instead:

```
import os
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = 'theano'
from keras import backend as K
```

With python3 it shows this output:

> Using Theano backend.
>
> Ungültiger Maschinenbefehl (Speicherabzug geschrieben)

How could I get further information about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from tensorflow import keras
```

If the problem persists, try going through the documentation on how to install and how to use it.

[Keras - Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras)

[Keras Overview - Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/overview)

[Keras.io](https://keras.io/)

Comment: with this import the backend message disappears. 
But the error persists.

Comment: Maybe I should mention  that theano itsself seems to work properly.
So to me it seems surprising that with theano backend the same error occurs.

Comment: further testing shows  that the tensorflow import seems to cause the problem.
Could it be, that keras imports tensorflow in any case (even if theano is 
explicitly defined as backend)?

Comment: I did read tensorflow installation instructions. There was one problem: pip and pip3 versions were <19, which I fixed. Then updgraded tensorflow, all other installation requirements seemed to be fullfilled. The error occures anyway.